# how to integrate a script into an application?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I made a script with casperjs that allows to make automatic purchases.

I want to make an application so that other people who do not coding can use it.

How can I put the script in the application and to be able to change information according to the person who uses it?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your current question is probably too broad for this website. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok thanks you i go to look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CasperJS command line parser](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/cli.html) to access **positional arguments** or **named options** to make changes to your program depending on the person who uses it.

For example:

```
$ casperjs example.js purchase automatic --username="johndoe" --password="qwerty123"

casper.echo(casper.cli.get(0)); // purchase
casper.echo(casper.cli.get(1)); // automatic
casper.echo(casper.cli.get('username')); // johndoe
casper.echo(casper.cli.get('password')); // qwerty123
```

Then, from your application, you can call the command using the arguments or options of your choice and obtain the result.

An alternative solution would be to use a CasperJS wrapper for the language you are using.

Here are some popular CasperJS wrappers:

- [SpookyJS (Node.js)](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS)
- [php-casperjs (PHP)](https://github.com/alwex/php-casperjs)
- [CasperJsHelper (.NET)](https://github.com/codeyu/CasperJsHelper)